# Hide multiple selected rows with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

Hi I've got a table populated by a mysql query with a checkbox in the first column.

```
while ($dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {        
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="width: 3%;"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[' . $lf . ']"/></td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 19%;"><strong>' . $dsatz["name"] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $lf = $lf + 1;
}
```

I would like to hide all selected rows with one click on a link/button at the bottom of the table.

This should be possible via css (display: none)  an jquery. but how would I do it?

Thanks for your help!
Seb

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/eGf8X/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$('yourbutton').click(function(){
    $('#yourtable tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').hide()
})
```

Comment: So for the stupid amongst us ( me included) this would be:
`$('hide1').click(
 function(){
    $('#table1 tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').hide()
 })`

for 

`<table class="table2" id="table1">`

and

`<input type = 'button' name = 'hide1' id='hide1' value = 'löschen' />`

if so, I'm getting a "TypeError: jQuery is undefined"

Comment: OK, sorry I'm pretty new to this. Unfortunately I'm getting a 'TypeError: jQuery is undefined' for this. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have jQuery included in the page? are you using noConflict() in your page?

Comment: whether the script is placed after jQuery is included in the page

Comment: Yes, jquery is included. Do you mean something like this: `var $ha = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$ha('#hide1').click(
 function(){
    $('#table1 tr').has('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').hide()
 })
`

Comment: is there any specific reason to call noConflict

Comment: yes it's placed after jQuery is included. and it's a wordpress page hence the noConflict

Comment: looks like you are calling `noConflict(true)` somewhere before the said lines.... also don't pass `trur` to `noConflict()`

Comment: Yes I am for a different function. `var $b = jQuery.noConflict(true);` Is there a solution to this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47559/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-seb)